# How does matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys matches font descriptors?

Tags: cocoa, fonts

I’m using the [-[NSFontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/NSFontDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002041-BAJJIFGF) method in order to find if a font is already installed in the system but I get very strange results.

Here is a small program to test if a given font matches an installed font:

```c
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void logFontDescriptor(NSString *message, NSFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor, NSArray *attributeKeys)
{
    printf("%s %s\n", [message UTF8String], [fontDescriptor.postscriptName UTF8String]);
    for (NSString *attributeKey in attributeKeys)
    {
        printf("    %30s -> %s\n", [[attributeKey description] UTF8String], [[[fontDescriptor objectForKey:attributeKey] description] UTF8String]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        if (argc != 2)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;

        NSArray *mandatoryKeys = @[ NSFontNameAttribute, NSFontFamilyAttribute, NSFontFaceAttribute ];

        NSURL *fontURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@(argv[1])];
        NSArray *fontDescriptors = CFBridgingRelease(CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fontURL));
        for (NSFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor in fontDescriptors)
        {
            logFontDescriptor(@"***", fontDescriptor, mandatoryKeys);

            NSArray *matchingFontDescriptors = [fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:[NSSet setWithArray:mandatoryKeys]];
            for (NSFontDescriptor *matchingFontDescriptor in matchingFontDescriptors)
            {
                logFontDescriptor(@"  MATCHING", matchingFontDescriptor, mandatoryKeys);
            }
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In order to reproduce the strange behavior, download the [Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-font-family-0.80.zip) and copy only the `Ubuntu-B.ttf` (*Ubuntu Bold*) file into your `~/Library/Fonts` directory. Then run this test program with `Ubuntu-R.ttf` (*Ubuntu Regular*):

```
./font_descriptor_matching ~/Downloads/ubuntu-font-family-0.80/Ubuntu-R.ttf
```

Now, you have the *Ubuntu Bold* font installed on your system and you are asking what font descriptors are matching *Ubuntu Regular* and here is the result (OS X 10.9.1):

```
*** Ubuntu
               NSFontNameAttribute -> Ubuntu
             NSFontFamilyAttribute -> Ubuntu
               NSFontFaceAttribute -> Regular

  MATCHING Ubuntu-Bold
               NSFontNameAttribute -> Ubuntu-Bold
             NSFontFamilyAttribute -> Ubuntu
               NSFontFaceAttribute -> Bold
```

Asking *Ubuntu Regular* what font matches its font name (`NSFontNameAttribute`), font family (`NSFontFamilyAttribute`) and font face (`NSFontFaceAttribute`) yields that the *Ubuntu Bold* font matches. As you can see, the only attribute that matches is the font family. Both the font name and font face are different yet the `matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:` method says that these fonts match.

Am I misunderstanding what the `matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:` method does or is it a bug?

**Additional Information:**

- If both the *Ubuntu Bold* and the *Ubuntu Regular* fonts are installed then the matching works as expected.
- This issue does not exist with all fonts.

Comment: I played with this a bit, it kind of looks like you’ve found a bug, but it’s an odd bug—I mean, how often are you matching against the traits from an uninstalled font?

I'm assuming that if Ubuntu-R.ttf is installed too, it works as expected? Or is that not true?

Comment: My app installs fonts so I want to make sure not to install a duplicate font. That’s why I’m matching against an uninstalled font. I updated the question with additional information and indeed if both fonts are installed, matching works as expected.

Comment: Sure sounds like you found a bug. Report a Radar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to workaround this odd behavior, I used this method which suppresses non matching font descriptors by explicitly testing all mandatory keys.

```
static NSArray * ReallyMatchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys(NSFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor, NSSet *mandatoryKeys)
{
    NSArray *matchingFontDescriptors = [fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:mandatoryKeys];
    NSMutableArray *reallyMatchingFontDescriptors = [matchingFontDescriptors mutableCopy];
    for (NSFontDescriptor *matchingFontDescriptor in matchingFontDescriptors)
    {
        BOOL reallyMatching = YES;
        for (NSString *mandatoryKey in mandatoryKeys)
        {
            if (![[fontDescriptor objectForKey:mandatoryKey] isEqual:[matchingFontDescriptor objectForKey:mandatoryKey]])
                reallyMatching = NO;
        }
        if (!reallyMatching)
            [reallyMatchingFontDescriptors removeObjectIdenticalTo:matchingFontDescriptor];
    }
    return [reallyMatchingFontDescriptors copy];
}
```